# Sails.js HOWTO: implement logging for HTTP requests

Tags: sails.js

With the poor default logging of Sails.js not showing http request logs(even on verbose). What is the best way implement http request logging to console so i can see if I am getting malformed requests? Expressjs's default logging would be enough.

I would prefer a Sails.js configuration way of doing it rather then a change the source code approach is possible.

Has anyone had experience with this. My google searches seem oddly lacking information.

Running Sails v0.9.8 on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's no Sails config option to log every request, but you can add a quick logging route at the top of `config/routes.js` that should do the trick:

```
// config/routes.js
'/*': function(req, res, next) {sails.log.verbose(req.method, req.url); next();}
```

Comment: If you are using Sails v.011 then there **is** a config option. See [Eagle's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31515047/1767377).

Comment: Can't argue with that, considering I wrote that code :)  And in fact, if you want to log _all_ HTTP requests (including static assets), using middleware is a better way to go.  It won't log requests made via sockets, though.

Answer (score 18):

Maybe too late, but for future references about this, I'm using Sails 0.11 and you can config that in the middleware, in the `config/http.js` file

Add this function (in fact it comes as an example)

```
// Logs each request to the console
requestLogger: function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("Requested :: ", req.method, req.url);
    return next();
},
```

And setup it on the `order` var:

```
order: [
  'startRequestTimer',
  'cookieParser',
  'session',
  'requestLogger',  // Just here
  'bodyParser',
  'handleBodyParserError',
  'compress',
  'methodOverride',
  'poweredBy',
  '$custom',
  'router',
  'www',
  'favicon',
  '404',
  '500'
]
```

Comment: But I couldnt find a way to use my sails logger in middlewares.

Comment: Can you explain better the problem? For me it's working perfectly

Comment: This solution works ok if its enough to output log with console.log. But if I want to output log information with sails.log.* then sails is not accessible in middleware and between my pretty sails log entries there are unformatted console.log entries.

I can imagine that I could load logger manually but that's inconvenient.

Comment: How would i modify the requestLogger function to output to file instead of consol?

Answer (score 3):

I forked the [sails-hook-requestlogger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-requestlogger) module to write all the request logs (access logs) to file.

## [sails-hook-requestlogger-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-requestlogger-file)

All you have to do is `npm install sails-hook-requestlogger-file` and you are good to go!

#### Usage

Just lift your app as normal and all your server requests will be logged, with useful information such as response-time, straight to your console. As a default it is activated in your dev environment but deactivated in production.

#### Configuration

By default, configuration lives in sails.config.requestloggerfile
You can create `config/requestlogger.js` and override these defaults:

```
Parameter        Type        Details
format           ((string))  Defines which logging format to use. Deaults to dev.
logLocation      ((string))  Defines where to log: console or file. Defaults to console.
fileLocation     ((string))  Location of file relative to project root (if file is specified in logLocation. This has no effect if console is specified in logLocation.
inDevelopment    ((boolean)) Whether or not to log requests in development environment. Defaults to true.
inProduction     ((boolean)) Whether or not to log requests in production environment Defaults to false.
```

#### Example `config/requestlogger.js` file:

```
module.exports.requestloggerfile = {
 //see: https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#predefined-formats for more formats
  format: ':remote-addr - [:date[clf]] ":method :url" :status :response-time ms ":user-agent"',
  logLocation: 'file',
  fileLocation: '/var/log/myapp/access.log',
  inDevelopment: true,
  inProduction: true
};
```

Hope that it would help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this matched my needs - it uses the Morgan module for Express and hooks it all up for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-requestlogger